# Create Botometer API to Python Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I want to use the botometer API on Python. I use Sypder 5 and so I use Anaconda for the installation of packages.

I get the following message when trying to install it.

(spyder-env) PS C:\Users\xxxx> conda install botometer
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- botometer

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-32
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Is there some other way to use botometer?

Comment: Did you try installing it with `pip`?  https://github.com/IUNetSci/botometer-python

Answer (score 0):

It's a pure Python library - just install it through Pip. You may want to install `tweepy` through Conda first though, since that is a dependency.

```bash
conda install -n spyder-env -c conda-forge tweepy
conda run -n spyder-env python -m pip install botometer
```